# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence error while cross validation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to make text sentiment but I got always this error.
My training data consists of two columns.
**List of occurrence (X):** This is the list of 0,1s based on occurrence of the words in the text document. There are 2115 values in each array. Looks like this: [0 0 1 ..., 0 0 0]. There is no missing values, each array has 2115 values.

**Label of the data (label):** This is also list of 0 and 1s based on sentiment. Looks like this: 1. There is just one value in each row for label.

My training sample has 1440 observations.[Here is my Data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gtut.png)

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

from sklearn.svm import SVC

from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve

from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit



def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=None, cv=None,
                    n_jobs=1, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5)):
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(title)
    if ylim is not None:
    plt.ylim(*ylim)
    plt.xlabel("Training examples")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.grid()

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                 train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                 color="r")
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                 test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
         label="Training score")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
         label="Cross-validation score")

    plt.legend(loc="best")
    return plt

    title = "Learning Curves (Naive Bayes)"
    cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=100, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    estimator = GaussianNB()

    plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, data.X, data.label, ylim=(0.3, 1.01), cv=cv, n_jobs=4)
```

When I run the code I got this error:

```
    /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array=231     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, ...
    Name: arrr, Length: 129, dtype: object, accept_sparse=False, dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>, order=None, copy=False, force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=True, allow_nd=False, ensure_min_samples=1, ensure_min_features=1, warn_on_dtype=False, estimator=None)
397 
398     if sp.issparse(array):
399         array = _ensure_sparse_format(array, accept_sparse, dtype, copy,
400                                       force_all_finite)
401     else:
    --> 402         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    array = 231     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, ...
    Name: arrr, Length: 129, dtype: object
    dtype = <class 'numpy.float64'>
    order = None
    copy = False
403 
404         if ensure_2d:
405             if array.ndim == 1:
406                 raise ValueError(

    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What should I do for solving this problem?
Thanks

Comment: which line of your code produced the error?

Comment: plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, data.X, data.label, ylim=(0.3, 1.01), cv=cv, n_jobs=4) line produces the error.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem occurs with the dimensions. I also changed the label into array. From pandas DataFrame to Numpy Array there exists "lists" in each array. So I changed as follows:

```
    featurelists=data.X.values.tolist()
    X=np.array(featurelists)
    y=data.label.as_matrix()
```

Now, it works.
Thanks all.